# Exploring classes and methods in VS

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

Im looking the name definition of this process so I can learn it properly. When I debug code in VS ill hover over a var before breakpoint to see what data is held in it and this window pops up which allows you to see methods and properties, there is usually a base item in it too. Is this called intellisense or something else?

I dont understand the difference between a lot of the items an how you find the thing (function?) you want - especially when things seem to be many levels deep in this window.

Thanks C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The window that pops-up is called a [*DataTip*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ea46xwzd(v=vs.140).aspx), the parts of a DataTip that let you examine the representation of a value are called [*Visualizers*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zayyhzts(v=vs.110).aspx).

See [Debugger Basics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k0k771bt.aspx).